# In Firefox how to delete multiple about:config entries at the same time?

Tags: firefox

I'm using a development version of Firefox, and there are a lot of custom entries in the about:config section that were added by extensions that are no longer installed. It's a really long list, and there is no obvious way to select all of them and delete them at the same time. It only allows to select and delete the entries one by one.

Is there any way to delete multiple entries at the same time in about:config?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A simple method would be to skip the about:config dialog.  Open the `prefs.js` file, which is in your Firefox profile, in a text editor while firefox isn't running.  Delete the lines you don't care about and then save.  Make a backup too if you want to be sure you don't trash something.